Pydantic Inheritance Defaults
How can I typehint a parent BaseModel such that a child subclass can provide defaults for some of the fields:
from pydantic import BaseModel


class Parent(BaseModel):
    first: str
    second: str
    third: str

    def run(self):
        print(self.first + self.second + self.third)


class Child(Parent):
    first = "1"
    second = "2"


c = Child(third="3")  # mypy: Missing named argument "first" for "Child" & Missing named argument "second" for "Child"


Use Field(default="...")
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field


class Parent(BaseModel):
    first: str
    second: str
    third: str

    def run(self):
        print(self.first + self.second + self.third)


class Child(Parent):
    first: str = Field(default="1")
    second: str = Field(default="2")


c = Child(third="3")

UPD: Actually, just specifying field types also works:
class Child(Parent):
    first: str = "1"
    second: str = "2"


Hmm, what linter are you using?

I use mypy 1.10.0. It shows 2 errors with your code and no issues if I just specify types

If you specify the type in the base class, you need to specify it in child classes.
Examples using:

Python 3.12.3
mypy==1.10.0
pydantic==2.7.4

For example, in you case:
from pydantic import BaseModel


class Parent(BaseModel):
    first: str # you added str type here
    second: str # you added str type here
    third: str

    def run(self):
        print(self.first + self.second + self.third)


class Child(Parent):
    first = "1" # but not here
    second = "2" # and not here too


c = Child(third="3")
# app.py:18: error: Missing named argument "first" for "Child"  [call-arg]
# app.py:18: error: Missing named argument "second" for "Child"  [call-arg]
# Found 2 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)

So the easiest way to solve this, is adding types to your child classes to:
from pydantic import BaseModel


class Parent(BaseModel):
    first: str
    second: str
    third: str

    def run(self):
        print(self.first + self.second + self.third)


class Child(Parent):
    first: str = "1" # added str type
    second: str = "2" # added str type


c = Child(third="3")
# Success: no issues found in 1 source file

Although not recommended, but if you don't want to specify types in the child, don't specify it in the base class:
from pydantic import BaseModel


class Parent(BaseModel):
    first = ""
    second = ""
    third: str

    def run(self):
        print(self.first + self.second + self.third)


class Child(Parent):
    first = "1"
    second = "2"


c = Child(third="3")
# Success: no issues found in 1 source file

